# Change TFS email template

Tags: tfs

Can I change the email template used by this TFS 2017 feature?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a folder under the TFS installation that hosts the templates for the eventing services alerts. You need to modify the xsl file corresponding to your event (in this case `WorkItemChangedEvent.xsl`) to change the formatting.

You can find this templates under `Drive:\%programfiles%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Transforms\1033` and after you modify it, you need to restart the application pool or the website because the templates are cached when the site starts.

P.S. Be sure to backup the original template and the changed one, because in future service packs or hotfixes Microsoft can replace this template and you'll loose your changes.

More info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb552337(v=vs.120)).